# how I must put my fingers for this tablature?

Tags: guitar, technique, fingering

How should I play this bar? I'm having trouble figuring out the fingering so that I can play it easily (or as easily as possible, anyways).

[image: music]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest barring your index finger across the 9th fret, and use your middle and ring fingers for the other notes, until you reach the last 5 notes. Move your index finger to the 8th fret of the B string, and then use your ring, middle, then index finger on the 12th, 10th, and 9th fret respectively on the D string.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: -1. Why would you use your 3rd finger for the 10th fret when using your 1st for the 9th. That makes no sense at all. You're cramming your 2nd finger out of the way and introducing an unnecessary stretch between 3rd and 4th finger. I hope you misread the tab.

Comment: I think we may have become confused in our finger terminology. I define the index finger = 2nd, then the middle finger = 3rd, and then the 4th finger.

Comment: @Alistair Maxwell: Your definitions are out of the ordinary for the US.  Explain up front next time...  +1 anyway.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that's not standard US fingering. Index is 1st. Also, given your update, -1 because you should be using your index, middle, and pinky (not ring). ;)

Comment: Thank you, should have realised that I am maybe a bit unconventional! :/ Will correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: @yossarian why would that be? I'm not arguing, I'm just interested to hear why the pinky should be used :)

Comment: In fact, I think your numbering scheme is pretty non-standard. A quick perusal of English guitar sites shows the index being referred to as 1 (check any chord chart).

Comment: In general, I think it's easier when playing 3 notes to a string to use the "one finger per fret" rule (although, I'll use my ring finger while playing a 3 fret stretch on a blues scale). However, in this particular case, I'd use the pinky because I think the string skip would be a stretch using the ring finger. It also creates a smaller stretch between the 8th and 12th.

Comment: Using the pinky is almost certainly more "correct". I'd bet any jazz or classical player would use their pinky. However, Clapton never seems to use his. He'd probably use the fingering you've suggested, so there you go. In general, it's a playing style thing. If you have a style, play it that way. However, since the OP couldn't figure out how to finger this themselves, I'd advocate the "correct" way of doing it.

Comment: I appreciate your update of the answer, but I still think your finger numbers are wrong. If that's how you refer to them, cool, but no one else does. I'd just remove the numbers altogether and use the terms index, middle, ring, pinky. Otherwise it's confusing to anyone that thinks in terms of the standard counting (even with the clarification).

Comment: Thinking about why I'd use my pinky a bit further, I'm more likely to use my pinky on a progression like 9 - 10 - 12, because using my ring finger feels like a stretch. However, if the progression was 9 - 11 - 12, then that feels more natural to use my middle / ring fingers. At that point the fingering would depend on the context of the line. (Sorry to go all comment happy on you here, btw)

Comment: Don't worry about it, thanks for clearing that up for me. I fully support your teaching of the technically correct way, the way I do it is just how I have picked it up. I will edit my answer again, and re-address my finger referencing :) I also now feel pretty cool in that I play guitar like Clapton, even if, you know, I can't actually *play* guitar like Clapton :P

Answer (score 3):

Use your index finger for the 9th fret, 2nd (middle) finger for the 10th fret, and your 4th (pinky) finger for the 12th fret. Given that it's 8th notes, I think a barre is probably unnecessary (unless it's very fast), but could be placed across the 9th fret.

When you get to the one note on the 8th fret, use your index finger. You'll then need to stretch for the 12th fret immediately after, but you'll then be back to the above fingering.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Ali Maxwell's answer, a barre would be useless as you don't go immediately from one string to another with the same fret. Even if you did have to go from one string to another on the same fret, you would use a technique called finger-rolling, where you roll your finger and hit the other string with the soft part of your finger and mute the previous string with the tip of your finger.  **For this one, you simply have to use your index finger for the 8th and 9th fret, your middle finger for the 10th fret and your pinky for the 12th fret.**

Practice with this riff slowly and increase the tempo as you would when learning any other riff.

Comment: Ah, probably better to comment on his answer rather than address issues with his answer in a separate answer.